# How to resolve Session 'app': error?

Tags: android, facebook, session, android-studio

I am making an app in android studio. I have used facebook integration into it.While running this app i am getting an error

```
11:02:14 AM Session 'app': running
11:02:19 AM Session 'app': error
```

and the app stops running. I didn't get any solution even after a lot of searching. So please help me out and assist in getting my app running. Any kind of assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some additional information? Do you receive some exceptions or messages in logcat? Did you try to execute app on another device/emulator?

Comment: @JohnSmith- This error i am getting in Event Log. No i didn't try. I am using my samsung Galaxy grand phone to run it.

Comment: @JohnSmith- i tried it on another phone but still showing the same error.

Comment: Param, if you are using Android Studio, try to open Android tab (Alt + 6) when you started your app. Logcat window should be shown.

Answer (score 3):

The solution that works for me is to unistall the app from my phone. I think it's due to having another version on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Right after commenting on your question, I found out what was wrong.
I used the 'release' flavor for debugging purposes. If I switch the flavor to 'debug', it works perfectly fine again.

Apparently 'release' has the the 'debuggable' configuration set to 'false' and 'debug' to true.

Answer (score 0):

check the Adb logs "Adb connection Error:EOF".

Go to android studio terminal
run  **adb kill-server** and **adb start-server**

Comment: I have the same issue and I could'nt find the specified adb log and the commands didn't help :/